# How to simplify function with Abs?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm trying to remove Abs below.

```
mylist = {{ConditionalExpression[Abs[x], x <= -1], 
    ConditionalExpression[x, x >= 1]}, {ConditionalExpression[
     Abs[-1 + x], x <= 0], 
    ConditionalExpression[-1 + x, 
     x >= 2]}, {ConditionalExpression[-1 + 2 x, x >= 1], 
    ConditionalExpression[1 - 2 x, x <= 0]}};
```

Expected result:

```
{{ConditionalExpression[-x, x <= -1], 
  ConditionalExpression[x, x >= 1]}, {ConditionalExpression[1 - x, 
   x <= 0], 
  ConditionalExpression[-1 + x, 
   x >= 2]}, {ConditionalExpression[-1 + 2 x, x >= 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[1 - 2 x, x <= 0]}}
```

I wrote this function but somehow it doesn't work well.

```
f1 = ConditionalExpression[
    Simplify[#, #[[2]] && x \[Element] Reals], #[[2]]] &;
Map[f1, mylist, {2}]
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PiecewiseExpand` does it.

**Edit**  and `// ComplexExpand // Simplify`  does it

```
mylist // ComplexExpand // Simplify

mylist // PiecewiseExpand

(*   {{ConditionalExpression[-x,        x <= -1], 
       ConditionalExpression[ x,        x >= 1]},
      {ConditionalExpression[ 1 - x,    x <= 0], 
       ConditionalExpression[-1 + x,    x >= 2]},  
      {ConditionalExpression[-1 + 2 x,  x >= 1], 
       ConditionalExpression[ 1 - 2 x,  x <= 0]}}   *)
```

But applying simple // ComplexExpand implies, that you already know that variables are at least Real.

Comment: I thought of that, but like an idiot, I didn't try it. +1

Comment: @MichaelE2 , happy that a real expert leaves something for average people to do.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Refine[Simplify[mylist], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

Comment: Simply `Refine[mylist, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` works for me.

Comment: One might also add that in terms of `Simplify`, `-x` is not simpler than `Abs[x]`. Compare ``Simplify`SimplifyCount[Abs[x]]``
and ``Simplify`SimplifyCount[-x]``.  So something like `Refine` or a complicated `ComplexityFunction` would need to be used.

Comment: That's right, @MichaelE2, thanks for clarifying that point. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's the `ComplexityFunction` way I referred to in [my comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267668/how-to-simplify-function-with-abs#comment667277_267670) just to illustrate the alternative:

```
Simplify[mylist, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
     5 Count[#, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] &)]
(*
{{ConditionalExpression[-x,        x <= -1], 
  ConditionalExpression[ x,        x >= 1]},
 {ConditionalExpression[ 1 - x,    x <= 0], 
  ConditionalExpression[-1 + x,    x >= 2]},
 {ConditionalExpression[-1 + 2 x,  x >= 1], 
  ConditionalExpression[ 1 - 2 x,  x <= 0]}}
*)
```

Note that `Simplify` is smart enough to use the condition in `ConditionalExpression`.  (I didn't realize that until now.  Or I forgot about it.)

The reason the OP was having trouble is that `-x` is not "simpler" than `Abs[x]`:

```
Simplify`SimplifyCount[Abs[x]]
(*  2  *)

Simplify`SimplifyCount[-x]
(*  4  *)
```

Examine the `FullForm` of `-x` and `Abs[x]` to see if you can spot why.